# new html input attributes usages

Tags: html

I am writing a signup form. While searching I have found an example form which the following

```
                      <input type="text"
                   id="phone_input"
           placeholder="Please Include Country Code"
           name="account[contact_phone]"
           tabindex="0"
           autocomplete="off"
           data-error-field="phone"/>
```

What is the use of naming this input box as account[contact_phone], and some input boxs have the same naming convention like account[email] account[fax] etc. What is the use of this arrayed naming?

what is data-error-field attribute means?

Answer (score 1):

your php `$_REQUEST` array will be filled as:

```
array('account' =>
  array(
    'contact_phone' => 'somevalue'
  )
);
```

with `account[contact_phone]` -like fields

[data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) are special attributes, you can get access to it from js:

```
document.querySelector('input').dataset['error-field'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use account[contact_phone] et cetera you can send the values as array to PHP. It's a little bit cleaner but doesn't change anything else.

Data Error Field is a special attribute for, e.g. Bootstrap, to highlight the field if there's an spelling error. If you type in an email in the phone field, the Field will e.g. glow up with the CSS settings for the "phone" data-error-field.